# API Gateway, 403 permission problem with the Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am following [this](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/secure-traffic-gcloud) instructions.

I've created a cloud function and it works well if I access it via URL provided by GCP, it returns "Hello World" and 200 status.
[image]

Then, I created GCP API Gateway with such config:

```
# openapi2-functions.yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: learning-words-trial
  description: Sample API on API Gateway with a Google Cloud Functions backend
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /hello:
    get:
      summary: Greet a user
      operationId: hello
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://us-central1-xxx.cloudfunctions.net/httptest2
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
```

Also, I set permissions, so the cloud function can be Invoked by the service account used by the Gateway API.

If I access Gateway API url `/hello`, I see such screen:
[image]

I haven't added any auth/security config so it should be available without this prompt.

But the main problem, if I click on "allow" it redirects me to an url `https://us-central1-xxx.cloudfunctions.net/httptest2` and then I see

```
Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /httptest2 from this server.
```

Please help me to understand where I could make a mistake.

---

Update 1:
, I suspect that this URL format from the article  `address: [GCP_REGION]-[PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net/[functionName]` is not valid. I replaced it with the link I got from the cloud function in the console `https://httptest2-xxxxxxx-uc.a.run.app` and it works. Not sure if it's the right decision though.

Comment: Did you grant the correct permission on the API Gateway service account?

Comment: Yes, it has "Cloud Function Invocation", I suspect that this URL format from the article ` address: https://GCP_REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/[name]` is not valid. I replaced it with the link I got from cloud function in console and it works

Comment: There are different reasons which cause the above error. You can check with this [Link](https://serverfault.com/questions/992839).

Comment: Because you use Cloud Functions 2nd generation, please add Cloud Run Invoker role to your service account. It should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this pattern `[GCP_REGION]-[PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net/[functionName]` works only with Cloud Functions gen1. In order to make it work with Gne 2, you should use new pattern  `https://[name]-[id]-uc.a.run.app`, you can copy URL from the cloud function view.